# Dynamically create a UserControl with parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, user-controls

I've created a `UserControl` that contains a grid.

In main page, users can select options from a combo, then, I need to generate a `UserControl` for each option that user's selected.

I've 2 problems:

1. I need to pass the parameters to the user control for configure the grid's datasource, but I don't know how to do it.
2. If I set default parameters for test, when a PostBack occurs, the user controls are removed.

Comment: please post some code. Can't you pass the parameter in the usercontrol constructor?

Answer (score -1):

I don't see any code of yours, so I leave you a simple example here.

First, define a property for the value you need to pass in:

```
public partial class SomeControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public int AProperty { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

So then, from the `aspx` where you need to use your user control, first register it as usual:

```
<%@ Register Src="~/MyControls/SomeControl.ascx" TagPrefix="my" TagName="SomeControl" %>
```

And later use it, and pass the value to the property, like this:

```
<my:SomeControl runat="server" ID="SomeControl1" AProperty="1" />
```

You can also set that property from the code behind of your `aspx` which contains the control, like this:

```
SomeControl1.AProperty = 1;
```

**Dynamic controls**
You can create this controls dynamically like this:

```
var ctrl = new SomeControl();
ctrl.AProperty = 1;
```

And later add those controls to a `<asp:PlaceHolder` in your `aspx`:

```
somePlaceHolder.Controls.Add(ctrl);
```

Upon postback (ie on selectedindexchanged of a dropdownlist), all the controls inside that place holder will desappear, but the information is still in your viewstate, so all you need to do is recreate the corresponding controls inside the same placeholder and the old values from viewstate will be attached to the recreated controls.